# Remap Space and Command

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, character-map

Basically, what I want to achieve is the second example here:

> As an example, we can make the space bar work as an additional ctrl key when held (similar to [Space2ctrl](https://github.com/r0adrunner/Space2Ctrl)) with the following sequence of commands.
>
> — https://github.com/alols/xcape#examples

Or here:

> This little hack for X turns the spacebar key into another control key when used in combination. When used alone, it behaves like the ordinary space bar on the key release event. Especially useful with Emacs.
>
> — https://github.com/r0adrunner/Space2Ctrl

So:

- <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> should send <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,
- while <kbd>Space</kbd> pressed **and released** should send one space character.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why? Is your control key broken?

Comment: @Arc676, there should be several whys in the docs I linked to. It’s because I want to avoid Emacs-related RSI. And I’ve been using this setup on Linux, so I’m quite used to it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install **[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)**.
2. Place this in your private.xml (`~/Library/Application Support/Karabiner`)

   ```
   <item>
           <name>Use Space as Command modifier</name>
           <identifier>private.space_command_key</identifier>
           <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::SPACE, KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::SPACE</autogen>
   </item>
   ```

   It goes in between the `<root>` and `</root>` tags.

   If you want to remap it to Control instead, you can change the `KeyCode::COMMAND_L` to `KeyCode::CONTROL_L`.
3. Launch Karabiner, press ⟳ ReloadXML, and check the box