# How to map "Spacebar + 1" to "⌃1" on Karabiner Elements?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

I'm looking for a way to remap `Spacebar` as a modifier for only the number row. For example, `Spacebar` + `0` = `⌃0`, but for anything else `Spacebar` is just `Spacebar`.

I found [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217328/remap-space-and-command) which does what I I want through the example of `M` + `N`. Unfortunately, it's for an older version of Karabiner, and I don't understand how this code translates to the current way the program works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually quite easy. From an example given on the page, I modified it so that `Spcebar` + `1` = `terminal command`. Works fairly well. Use Karabiner Event Viewer to know the name of the key you want to add, and place this as a .json file on `.config > karabiner > assets > complex_modifications`

```
{
    "title": "Spacebar + 1",
    "rules": [        
        {
            "description": "Spacebar + 1",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": {
                        "simultaneous": [
                            {
                                "key_code": "spacebar"
                            },
                            {
                                "key_code": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "shell_command": "open /Users/"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "it's quite easy" If you say so.